# setting background image based on html attribute on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im currently trying to get a nice div structure for adding video content to my website via a div. I have it set up as such where vidurl is the video url, and srcpost is the div's background image as well as poster image loaded when that video is selected.

My question basically is why wont this work? I checked online for a similar use case and I guess I just couldnt figure out how to ask properly or theres something im just not doing correctly. I had it working when I had the attr srcpost containing url("") within it, but if possible I'd like remove that from the html.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   loadbgimg();
});

function loadbgimg() {
   $( '.video_selection' ).each(function() {
      var backgroundimg = $( this ).attr( 'srcpost' ).replace('%', ' ');
      $( this ).css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundimg + ')');
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='video_selection' vidurl='http://localhost/movies/Napoleon%Dynamite/napdyn.mp4' 
srcpost='http://localhost/movies/Napoleon%Dynamite/poster.jpg'>
<p>Napoleon Dynamite</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your jQuery --    I've tested it using a publicly available image:  https://jsfiddle.net/1gouamkn/   --  Make sure your script can "see" the image on your server, that you have permissions set to display it, etc etc ..  Maybe even try a relative path IE  `/movies/Napoleon%Dynamite/poster.jpg`  -- The point is, that your code is good .. If that image exists.

Comment: @zak could it be the replacement of % with empty space causing his issue. In your fiddle your image path does not have %. Secondly I don't think replacing the % with space is a good idea, it is a url encoded address.

Comment: @Zak hey man thanks for the reply, the image is publicly available. I know because part of my jquery that does work unlike this part is it sets the videojs poster to that same url and it works perfectly. I cant seem to figure out what the dealio is with this though.

EDIT: https://imgur.com/0pKbeWd heres a imgur of the output of my site. The divs at the bottom with the text is suppose to have the background image. But the poster is clearly seen up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script works! Check out the snippet below with your code, a little added CSS and working images.

My guess is your image path is incorrect. Try to go to http://localhost/movies/Napoleon%Dynamite/poster.jpg in your browser and see if your image is actually there.

If your image path is correct, check the console in [Chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). Maybe that will give you some answers. Either way, the issue isn’t your script. Hope this helps!

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   loadbgimg();
});

function loadbgimg() {
   $( '.video_selection' ).each(function() {
      var backgroundimg = $( this ).attr( 'srcpost' ).replace('%', ' ');
      $( this ).css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundimg + ')');
   });
}
```

```css
.video_selection {
   padding: 10px;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='video_selection' vidurl='http://localhost/movies/Napoleon%Dynamite/napdyn.mp4' srcpost='http://placekitten.com/600/300'>
<p>Napoleon Dynamite</p>
</div>

<div class='video_selection' vidurl='http://localhost/movies/Napoleon%Dynamite/napdyn.mp4' srcpost='http://placekitten.com/800/300'>
<p>Another video</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man you made me realize I needed %20 in between Napoleon and Dynamite instead of just the single %. I knew I wasnt crazy!